# Netsuite items sorted by last count date

Tags: netsuite, inventory-management

I am new to NetSuite. I have set up Calculated Inventory Counts and want to set up some reports based on the counts we have done.

I am attempting to set up a saved search for Items so that I can see which individual items were counted during a range of days, how many adjustments were made as a result, etc.

Unfortunately, I don't see a way to sort items by last count date.

I would be surprised if this has not come up before, but I have searched and not found any relevant answers

Any guidance is appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Quick answer to get you started: in the Results tab, scroll down to the bottom of the Field drop-down and you will see entries that are followed by and ellipsis ("...").  These are the available joined tables.  You can select fields from there that are not present on the record type that you are searching, but *are* present on linked records.

For example: the Last Count Date is not a field on an Inventory Count transaction, but is on the Item record instead.  Scroll down (as per above) to "Item Fields..." and then select Last Count Date from the pop-up list to include that field on the search.